# Recuperando o estado da aplicação ao selecionar um item no GridView

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, windows-10

Olá, estou criando uma aplicação universal para o Windows 10 em C#. Na tela inicial tem um GridView carregando dezenas de item. Gostaria de saber como devo salvar o item selecionado sem precisar depois quando voltar para a tela inicial, deslizar até chegar ao ultimo item visto ? Obrigado.

Comment: Seria favoritar o item?

Comment: Não, sempre que seleciono um item e navego para a outra tela, na volta ele não carrega onde parei, ele recarrega a lista como se tivesse abrido o app pela primeira vez

Comment: Não há como salvar o index do item selecionado, igual ao cookie que utilizamos em paginas web?

Comment: Nossa, então tenho pensar em algo. Até o momento tenho 41 itens no gridview, até eu chegar ao 39 tenho que deslizar o dedo na tela até chegar, depois que clico e navego para a segunda tela e volto, terei que deslizar tudo de novo para chegar e selecionar o item 40.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Basta utilizar o [cache de navegação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcachemode(v=vs.95).aspx) `NavigationCacheMode`. Há três modos:

`NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled` - A página não é mantida em cache, ou seja, após sair da tela e voltar, a tela será reinicializada.

`NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled` - A página será mantida em cache enquanto houver memória sobrando, mas se o aplicativo precisar de mais memória, ela será liberada do cache.

`NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required` - A página é mantida no cache a todo custo, mesmo que não haja mais memória disponível.

Adicione isto na inicialização da página, logo após o `InitializeComponent()`

Após isto, ao navegar para a segunda tela e voltar a tela inicial se manterá inalterada (caso escolha a opção `Required`ou `Enabled`).

Vale lembrar que o controle do cache é feito individualmente em cada página. O cache da página 1 não afetará a página 2.

Comment: Cara você salvou a pátria. Muito obrigado